# Saving All Cache Database Queries

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I am new to the caching side of thing for codeigniter I am trying to understand the user guide https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

But I would like to be able to save all database queries that come from controller/model.

I do not know how to use it properly. `$this->cache->save('store')` where **store** is the controller name.

If I do that will it save all database queries or do I have it wrong. I don't want to save individual queries rather the whole lot. On the controller.

**Have I got this correct?** `$this->cache->save('store')` where **store** is the controller name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the examples in documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

```
$data = array();
$data_to_save = $this->load->view('example',$data,true);
$this->cache->save('name_of_cache_key', $data_to_save, 300);
echo $data_to_save;
```

You can cache your html. In the top of your controller you can check if cache exist - don't do queries, only show cache. If not exist - do all php and queries and save in cache.

Comment: I have been reading it and don't under stand 'name of cache key'

Comment: It's your choice. Don't have link with controller name.